# About Uncle Ben's famous quote "With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility"

Tags: ambiguity

> With great power comes great responsibility

I can see that it is inverted to emphasize great power and responsibility.

However, when I reverse it to a normal order(?), it is not only mundane but
the cause and effect relationship(?) also seems wrong.

> Great responsibility comes with great power

It sounds like great responsibility comes first and great power follows it.
Shouldn't it be reversed? According to the context, the sentence should be

> Great power comes with great responsibility?

Does **Come with** have a connotation that the subject and object moves
simultaneously?

What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: You have responsibility because of your power, so your second version isn't quite right. If you want to flip the position of the nouns, then (semantically) it should be *great responsibility comes* ***from*** *great power*. (Or, in longer form, *Having great responsibility is a consequence of having great power.*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression “come with” is used to indicate that one action is the consequence of another.

***[Come with (something)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-with)***

> to exist or develop as a result of something
>
> - the kind of skill that comes with years of practice.

(MacMillan Dictionary)

So you have “great responsibility” as a result of having “great power”.

Comment: +1 But I think you should emphasize your answer to match his real question of flipping the sentence around, "With A comes B" = "B comes with A" and both equal "A is result of B".